# Assembler Intel x86 Loop n times with user input

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, intel

I'm learning x86 assembly and I'm trying to write a program that reads a number n (2 digits) from user input and iterate n times.

I've tried many ways but I get an infinite loop or segment fault.

```
input:

    push    msgInputQty
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4

    push    quantity    
    call    gets    
    add esp, 4

    mov     ecx, 2
    mov     eax, 0
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     edi, 0
    mov     dl, 10

transform:
    mul     dl

    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     bl, byte[quantity+edi]
    sub     bl, 30h

    add     eax, ebx

    inc     edi

    loop    transform

    mov ecx, eax

printNTimes:

    push    msgDig
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4
        loop printNTimes
```

I'd like to save in ecx and iterate n times this number

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it in a debugger line by line. At what point does the program do something that doesn't match what you expected?

Comment: You string-to-int loop is pretty overcomplicated.  It potentially overflows with 3-digit numbers (unless you use a more normal `imul eax, eax, 10` instead of an 8-bit `mul`), so you might as well just fully unroll with one `imul`.  And BTW, `movzx ebx, byte [quantity+edi]` can replace `mov ebx,0` + merging into the low byte of `bl`.  And you can compute your integer in the register you want as a loop counter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ecx` register is being blown away by the call to `printf`.

`ecx` is a volatile register in some calling conventions and its likely that your `loop` is being corrupted by what `printf` is leaving in there.

To begin with, I would follow Raymond's advice in the comment attached to your original question and attach a debugger to witness this behaviour for yourself.

As for a solution, you can try preserving `ecx` and restoring it after the call to see the difference:

```
; for example
mov edi,ecx
call printf
mov ecx,edi
```

There may be more issues here (hard to know for sure since your code is incomplete ... but things like your stack allocations that don't appear to be for any reason are interesting) - but that is a good place to start.

Peter has left a comment under my answer to point out that you could remove the issue *and* optimize my solution by just not using `ecx` for your loop at all and instead do it manually, making your code change:

```
   mov edi, eax

printNTimes:

    push msgDig
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    dec edi
    jnz printNTimes
```

Comment: If you're going to use `edi` at all, just keep your loop counter in EDI and replace `loop` with `dec edi/jnz`.  The `loop` instruction is *only* useful as a code-size optimization for `dec ecx/jnz` if using ECX for your loop counter is convenient.  It's a performance de-optimization on modern Intel CPUs so compilers never use it.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, that is useful info. I will be honest and say I had no idea - however my original answer was just to demonstrate the issue in a clear way. I'll point the OP at your comment though for a proper optimization - thanks again!

Comment: See [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](//stackoverflow.com/q/35742570).  Anyway, I think in this case, there's no need to suggest a save/restore since that's a more complicated fix vs. just choosing a call-preserved register for looping.  (And phrasing it that way *implicitly* makes the point that `loop` isn't the only way to loop, without going into detail.)